# ¿Cómo usar floodfill en una matriz?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matriz

### RECURSION

Una imagen esta siendo representada por una matriz **(M x N)** llena de enteros, donde `imagen[i][j]` representa un pixel de la imagen.

Se van a dar 3 valores, *X*, *Y* y *ColorNuevo* con los que debes realizar un algoritmo de relleno.

Un algoritmo de relleno consiste en tomar el valor del pixel `imagen[X][Y]` y reemplazar a este y a todos sus pixeles adyacentes (y a los adyacentes de los adyacentes, etc...) que tengan el mismo color al del pixel `imagen[X][Y]` por el *ColorNuevo*.

Un pixel adyacente solo son los de arriba, abajo, izquierda y derecha, no diagonalmente.

### Entrada

No hay que recibir nada, la función dada tiene la matriz a recibir, el X y Y (La coordenada de inicio) y el *ColorNuevo* como parámetro.

### Salida

Retornar la matriz modificada, NO CREAR UNA NUEVA, operar sobre la original.

### Ejemplo 1:

Input:

```
matriz = [[1,1,1],[1,1,0],[1,0,1]]   X=1 Y=1 ColorNuevo = 2
```

Output:

```
[[2,2,2],[2,2,0],[2,0,1]]
```

Llevo esto pero no se que mas hacer:

```py
class Paint: 
    def floodFill(image, x, y, newColor):
        cur_color = image[x][y]
        heigth = len(image)
        width = len(image[0])

     def dfs(x,y):
         if 0 <= x < heigth and 0 <= width and image[x][y] == cur_color and image[x][y] != newColor:
             image[x][y] = newColor
             dfs(x+1,y)
             dfs(x-1,y)
             dfs(x+1,y+1)
             dfs(x+1,y-1)

        dfs(x,y)
        return image
```

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado hasta el momento? ¿Qué problemas has tenido? Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: class Paint: 
        def floodFill(image, x, y, newColor):
            cur_color = image[x][y]
            heigth = len(image)
            width = len(image[0])

            def dfs(x,y):
                if 0 <= x < heigth and 0 <= width and image[x][y] == cur_color and image[x][y] != newColor:
                    image[x][y] = newColor
                    dfs(x+1,y)
                    dfs(x-1,y)
                    dfs(x+1,y+1)
                    dfs(x+1,y-1)

            dfs(x,y)
            return image

Comment: pero no se que mas hacer ;v

Comment: agregalo a la pregunta, aquí no se ve bien

Comment: listo ya lo agregue

Comment: listo ya puedes revisar.